# I have different zip files that contain one csv file each. how do I unzip each folder, and save all the csv files in one folder

Tags: python, unzip

The codes I have written, for some reasons does not work.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import zipfile

path = r"C:/Users/nano/Documents/Project" # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.gz")

for folder in all_files:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(folder,"r") as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(path)
```

Comment: Define "does not work".

Answer (score 1):

First you are using Zip against Gzip.  So you need to use the right library.  Below is a working example of the code.

```
import glob
import os
import gzip

path = r"C:/Temp/Unzip" # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.gz")
print(all_files)
for file in all_files:
    path, filename = os.path.split(file)
    filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    with gzip.open(file,"rb") as gz:
        with open('{0}/{1}.csv'.format(path, filename), 'wb') as cv:
            cv.writelines(gz.read())
```

Comment: I always wondered about the `rb` (vs `rt`, I believe, as in bytes versus text) setting in gzip; is there a reason why we would use `b` here, e.g. over `t`?

Comment: On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that in JPEG or EXE files.

Comment: Since I just want the exact contents of the data without manipulation, I pick b.

Answer (score 1):

gzip (.gz) and zip (.zip) are two different things. For gzip, you can use `gzip`:

```
import glob
import gzip
import shutil

path = r"C:/Users/shedez/Documents/Project" # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.gz")

for folder in all_files:
     dst=folder[:-3] # destination file name
     with gzip.open(folder, 'rb') as f_in, open(dst, 'wb') as f_out:
         shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use gz (gZip) format, you might want to look at the `gzip` package, I'm not aware of an extract method, but you can do something as such, using pandas purely, which i find more convenient:

```
for folder in all_files:
    c = pd.read_csv(folder, compression='gzip')
    c.to_csv(path+folder[:-2]+"csv")
```

the [:-2] is to cut the "gz", and you might want to either change the parameters of read_csv (adding header row, or whatever) or the flags of to_csv (setting the arguments `header=False, index_label=False` to prevent panda adding you undesired stuff

alternatively, you could open it with `gzip`

```
import gzip
import shutil
with open(folder, 'rb') as f_in, gzip.open(folder[:-2]+"csv", 'wb') as f_out:
    shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try out this code:

```
import os, zipfile

dir_name = 'C:\\Users\\shedez\\Documents\\Project' # ZIP location
extract_dir_name = 'C:\\Users\\shedez\\Documents\\Project\\Unziped' # CSV location after unzip
extension = ".zip" # you might have to change this

os.chdir(dir_name) # change directory from working dir to dir with files

for item in os.listdir(dir_name): # loop through items in dir
    if item.endswith(extension): # check for ".zip" extension
        file_name = os.path.abspath(item) # get full path of files
        zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) # create zipfile object
        zip_ref.extractall(extract_dir_name) # extract file to dir
        zip_ref.close() # close file
```

If you want to learn more about **zipFile**, click [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html).